# Highcharts Pulling JSON data into series names dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Ok, so here is my problem. I am building a scatter plot chart with 4 quadrants that are labeled. However I need to pull JSON data into the chart and dymanically label the series instead of how I have it now.

https://jsfiddle.net/oh3hevwr/5/

In other words, I need this code specifically to be populated by the JSON data. I know how to pull in the JSON data, but not how to bring in the series name, color, and id within the string.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Properly Used',
            color: '#23d207',
            id: 1,
            data: []...etc.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's wrong. Looking at the JSFiddle the graph seems accurate.

Comment: I am wanting to pull in the data by an outside JSON string and not by the hard coded data in the example.

Comment: Well you need to first get the JSON if you don't have it. That may be an ajax call or storing into a variable. Then you can iterate over it to get the information you want. So your hardcoded series part will likely change. I suggest researching ajax calls and how to transverse the nodes, if i understand you correctly.

Comment: Can you obtain the information via an ajax call even? Or do you need help  with that part?

Comment: I do know how to pull in the data with a JSON string. However, I am getting hung up when I have to separate the data by the 4 quadrants. for instance,  
`$.getJSON('js/whichtellersareusingthemachines.json', function(json) {
    options.series[0].data=json.data[0];
    options.series[1].data=json.data[1];
    options.series[2].data=json.data[2];
    options.series[3].data=json.data[3];
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });`

Comment: I see what you mean. I think this question should be in two parts. What is the format of the JSON and to what format do you want to transform to. And the second part should be how to apply that. Could you show what the original format is. Then it would be easy to transform that into what the chart needs.

Comment: How your JSON does it look like ?

Comment: It all depends on the format of your JSON. We can't tell you how to get the information from your JSON without knowing exactly what your JSON looks like.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Been sick for the past few days. You can see my JSON string here: https://jacturne.hostingmyself.com/json/data.json

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this very easy.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

You'll want to make it so that the chart does not instantiate until your AJAX call has completed successfully. Wrap that code into a function that accepts a `series` parameter, and then call it with JSON data obtained through the jQuery `getJSON` function to render the highchart with your information.